# Get couchdb views to process design-docs as well as other docs

Tags: couchdb

I am trying to get a view in couchdb to include design docs. I have done it in the past, but can not get it to work today.

In a past couchapp there is a file called `options.json` that contains the text:

```
{
  "include_design": "true"
}
```

This results in the design doc containing

```
"options": {
   "include_design": "true"
},
```

I added this to the new project, but still the design doc is not processed by my views. Is there something that I missed?

---

CouchDB 1.7.1

Comment: Did you try to add `"options": {
   "include_design": "true"
},` manually to a design doc and see what will happen?

Comment: @user3405291 I checked, it is in the design doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/ddoc/views.html#view-options), `include_design` option is a `boolean`.

---

I double-checked CouchDB to see how it saves `Boolean` values by adding a document to a sample database with a `Boolean` value for one of  the keys:

```
$ cat doc--0000 
{"time":"2011", "address":"CT", "include":true}
$ curl -k -X PUT https://admin:**@192.168.1.106:6984/sample/doc--0000 -d @doc--0000 
{"ok":true,"id":"doc--0000","rev":"1-e269c17275e2d21ba9100cd65b304d70"}
$ curl -k -X GET https://admin:**@192.168.1.106:6984/sample/doc--0000 
{"_id":"doc--0000","_rev":"1-e269c17275e2d21ba9100cd65b304d70","time":"2011","address":"CT","include":true}
```

The double-check confirms that the `Boolean` values are saved as `true` NOT `"true"`. I'm not sure, maybe that's the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

@user3405291 is correct the problem is with the string `"true"` instead of boolean `true`. CouchDB doesn't save this. Your view is run on the server as a javascript script so you should write it like you write javascript anywhere.